# stored procedure getting struck from java but working fine from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, callable-statement

```
public void createCostRecord() throws Exception 
{       
    Context ctx = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    boolean spReturn = false;

     try{ 
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("CSMWebAppjndi");
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            String sp = "{call usp_CreateCostRecords(?,?)}"; 
                    ps = conn.prepareCall(sp);
                    ps.setInt(1, 1000);
                    ps.setInt(2, 2000);
                    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                    {
                    ps.executeQuery();
                    }
     } catch (NamingException e) 
     {
                log.error(e,e);
     } catch (SQLException e) 
     {
                log.error(e,e);
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         log.error(e,e);
     }
     finally {
              if(rs!=null){
                rs.close();
              }
              if(ps!=null){
                ps.close();
              }
              if(conn != null){
                conn.close();                    
              }
              if(ctx != null ){
                ctx.close(); 
              }
            }
}
```

while calling the above method the line number 23 executeQuery works fine for the first iteration of the for loop, 
on second iteration of the for loop its getting struck at executeQuery and the procedure never completes execution.

But the weird thing is while i try the same procedure with same input from SQL developer its getting executed for any number of times without any struck.

Anyone help me to understand why the procedure from java is getting struck at second attempt and but its working fine in SQL developer.

Comment: Look and v$session view and see what the session is doing.

Comment: You are using `executeQuery`, so presumably the stored procedures returns a `ResultSet`, in that case you should iterate over the result set to retrieve rows (which likely cause the execution of the stored procedure to continue) and close it when you're done. This is just a theory, I'm not sure if it will actually solves the problem; so I didn't post as an answer.